# Docker rails run server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, httpserver

I'm new in Docker. I have a container where i installed ubuntu. I also installed ruby and rails framework. I would like to run rails server and see my page on localhost:3000 or other port. To execute a container i do:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash.
```

Inside of container i just do:

```
root@ed2727e0cd0f:/home/myrails/myPage: rails server

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-08-08 13:29:07] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-08-08 13:29:07] INFO  ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-08-08 13:29:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=127 port=3000
^C[2015-08-08 13:29:15] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2015-08-08 13:29:15] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

my netstat inside the container is:

```
root@ed2727e0cd0f:/# netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3000                :::*                    LISTEN     
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
```

When i access localhost:3000 via browser it occurs `Unable to Connect`. I believe that this have to do with container configuration, am i right? Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile? When you are in you container after `docker exec` can you check with `netstat -an` ?

Comment: I have no dockerfile. This is a container that i've created.. It is possible to create a Dockerfile from a container? Or i must to create a image from my container first? My question was updated with netstat log.

Comment: Yes, have a look at https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image

Comment: I notice `127.0.0.1:3000` should be `0.0.0.0:3000`?

Comment: I suggest you to add the `-p` option `docker run --name app -t -i -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 /bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to familiarize yourself with `docker-compose`, it will help a lot.  [docker-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails) is a project I just created to make rails with docker (and CI) *very easy*.  Look at the `development` configuration for ideas, also checkout the [wiki](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails/wiki/Prerequisites) for prerequisites/setup.  If you are on OSX, dinghy is quite helpful, whereas ubuntu is just a vanilla setup for the most part (though you may have to adjust the UFW as mention on that page).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.. What i've done was to build my own bridge. I don't know if this is necessary, probably is not since that docker has one by default but i follow this topic:

[Building your own Bridge](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#bridge-building)

and then inside of my container i run rails server with the bridge's ip which in my case is the following command:

```
root@ed2727e0cd0f:/home/myrails/myPage: rails server -p 3000 -b 192.168.5.2
```